# What is the derivative of $y=\cos(x+y)$?

Tags: calculus

I know it'll be solved using chain rule but I don't know how to use chain rule formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $y=\cos(x+y)$

Differentiating using [chain rule](http://www.actucation.com/calculus-1/derivative/different-rules-for-derivative/problems-on-combination-of-rules)

$ \dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x} =−\sin⁡(x+y)(x+y) \; \Rightarrow$

$\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}=−\sin⁡(x+y)\left(1+\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}\right)$

Rewriting,

$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=−\sin⁡(x+y)−\sin⁡(x+y)\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} \; \Rightarrow$

$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}+\sin⁡(x+y)\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=−\sin⁡(x+y)$

Taking $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ common,

$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\left(1+\sin⁡(x+y)\right)=−\sin⁡(x+y)$

Bringing $(1+\sin⁡(x+y))$ to other side,

$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=−\dfrac{\sin⁡(x+y)}{1+\sin⁡(x+y)}$ will be the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiating the sides wrt $x$ yields:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(1+\frac{dy}{dx})(-\sin(x+y))$$

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative of both sides

> $$y' = -\sin(x+y)\cdot (1+y')$$

Now just solve,

$$y' = {-\sin(x+y)\over 1+\sin(x+y)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Implicit differentiation is also useful.

Consider $$F=y-\cos(x+y)=0$$ Computing the partial derivatives $$F'_x=\sin(x+y)\qquad, \qquad F'_y=1+\sin(x+y)$$ By the implicit function theorem $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=-\frac{\sin(x+y)}{1+\sin(x+y)}$$

Comment: Don't you use the notation $f_x$ to mean the partial derivative wrt $x$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom. Well, it is a question of notation. I use this one since this what I awas teached (looooong time ago). To be rigorous it should be $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$